# Given that L is regular, how to prove that Opp(L) is regular?

Tags: formal-languages

I've been struggling with the following question:

Let $L$ be a regular language. We define $OPP(L)$ to be:
$OPP(L)=\{uv~|~vu~\text{belong to}~L\}$

prove that if $L$ belongs to $Ldfa$ then $OPP(L)$ also belongs to $Ldfa$.

---

Thing is,
We've learned that $Lreg=Lfa$,
meaning,
if I was able to prove that $OPP(L)$ is regular, that would mean that it's possible to generate a Finite Automaton for the language.

I tried proving it's regularity using Induction over $|r|$ where $r$ is the regular expression of $L$ (we know $L$ is regular, therefore, a regular expression $r$ exists that $L(r)=L$), but I got kinda lost trying to perform the induction step.

Any help/leads will be much appreciated.

Comment: Voted to migrate to Math.SE.

Comment: See [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/prove-that-regular-languages-are-closed-under-the-cycle-operator).